# Default Control Template of ProgressBar Control in WinUI 3

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I am working on a WinUI 3 app and I am not able to find a way to change the control template of the `ProgressBar`.

My actual requirement is to change the height of "Track Line".

Check below image. I want to change height of this thin line marked in Red.

[image]

I can change default control template as well if you can share the whole style of `ProgressBar` in WinUI 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the default template of `ProgressBar` in this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/ProgressBar/ProgressBar.xaml).

If you want to set the height only, you can override the `ProgressBarTrackHeight` resource (see line 232 in the source code)

In essence you can just create a new `ThemeResource` with the same key in your code to override the default value.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-theme-resources

Hope this helps